# Mouse click event mixing up with move down nd mouse up events in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have an operation that requires me to use Mouse Click, Mouse Down and Mouse Up events. However, the Mouse Down and Mouse Up events are being called when the Mouse Click event occurs. i.e. They are over riding the Click Event. Any ideas of how to work around this situation. I have to use these events in order to complete the operation in the viewport. 
I am using Win Forms events with C#.

Comment: You are trying to have one user action do too much, you cannot both select the line, drag it *and* change the endpoint of a line with a single mouse operation.  The standard UI solution for this is the one you see used in the Winforms designer.  You draw drag handles on the line endpoints.  If the user clicks on a drag handle then he wants to move the endpoint.  If not and clicks on the line then he wants to move the line.

Answer (score 1):

first of all Why you want to use all three events ? In which order you expect these events to be fired?

**mousedown**
Fires when the user depresses the mouse button.

**mouseup**
Fires when the user releases the mouse button.

**click**
Fires when a mousedown and mouseup event occur on the same element.

Mouse Click = Mouse Down + Mouse Up

So definitely if you have all three events in your form  all of them will be fired.

Comment: Well, On Mouse Click, I m selecting a Line in the ViewPort.... And On MouseDown again, I have to select the Start or End Point and allow Drag. I m using Mouse Move for this. And finally OnMouseUp, I have to update the line's start or end point to its new position. How do I go about it?